# MenuItem in Orchard cms

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

I want to add a new menu item in the admin page. However hasn't succeed.

I created AdminMenu in my Project as :

```
 public class AdminMenu : INavigationProvider 
     {
      public AdminMenu()
      {
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
       }
 private Localizer T { get; set; }
 public string MenuName { get { return "admin"; } }


 public void GetNavigation(NavigationBuilder builder)
   {
     builder.AddImageSet("UsedEquipProperty").Add(T("UsedEquipProperty"), "7",   BuildUsedEquipmentProperty);
   }
   private void BuildUsedEquipmentProperty(NavigationItemBuilder menu)
    {
     menu.Add(T("UsedEquipProperty"), "7.1", item => item.Action("Index",      "UsedEquipmentProperty", new { area = "MyModule"   }).Permission(Permissions.EditOwnContent));

     menu.Add(T("Create Property"), "7.2", item => item.Action("Create",   "UsedEquipmentProperty", new { area = "MyModule" }).Permission(Permissions.EditOwnContent));
}
```

Am I missing something? I cant see my added menu item on the admin page.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the logs? Have you enabled the module?

Comment: It was not showing because the module was disabled.Thanks